# Firebase offline data not save like images

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

After getting an image and text from Firebase into the app online, then how can the image and text be saved automatically into mobile, if we open the app a second time without an Internet connection, show image the text offline? How can I do this?

```
public class offline extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Only the text is offline, not images.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?